# Using Relative Paths with Matlab Coder

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I am trying to generate C code for a Matlab function. It uses mongoose web server for communication. If I place the `.h/.c` files in the same folder as the `.m` file I can compile everything fine using:

```
coder.cinclude('mongoose.h');
coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','mongoose.c');
coder.cinclude('rest.h');
coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','rest.c');
```

I would like to keep my `.c` files and `.m` files separate, so moving C files to a folder named `native/` causes compilation to fail as expected. Thus, I tell Matlab where to find them using:

```
customDir = '/full/path/to/native';
coder.updateBuildInfo('addIncludePaths', customDir);
coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourcePaths', customDir);
```

Which works. However it works only with absolute paths and not with relative paths. This is a problem since each contributor to this projects keeps the source folder in a different location. What is the proper way to tell Matlab native file locations using relative paths to Matlab working directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate C code (and not compile), I'd suggesting adding the relative locations to those files to the Matlab Path. You can do this with:

`addpath('the_relative_path_to_native')`

Or even better:

`addpath(fullfile(cd(), 'the_relative_path_to_native'))`

After issuing this command, Matlab searches this folder for .m function as well as included C files. This should solve your problem as described.

But later, if you want to compile the generated code, the included folders will not be copied/merged/included in the `codegen` directory created by Matlab, so you should handle that in a different manner, such as including the directory in your custom `makefile` os adding a command to copy the required files to a folder convenient for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `$(START_DIR)` marcro which gives you the path to the working folder of your project.

Just just neet to specify where your source files are relative to this path then